# How to use more than two buttons in dialog box

Tags: android

In AlertDialog , I can use two types of button, negative button and positive button. But If I want to use more than two buttons what I need to do?
The following program Is not working ..

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        QuizActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Quiz Result");
                alert.setMessage("Correct Answer: "
                        + scoreMode.getCorrectAnswer() + "\n"
                        + "Wrong Answer: " + scoreMode.getWrongAnswer()
                        + "\n" + "Total Score: "
                        + scoreMode.getScorePoint() + "\n"
                        + "Bonus Score: " + scoreMode.getBonusPoint());
                alert.setPositiveButton("Save result",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                    int arg1) {
                                showSaveResultDailog(scoreMode
                                        .getScorePoint());
                            }

                        });
                alert.setNegativeButton("Play Again",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                    int arg1) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,
                                        QuizOptionActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });
                alert.setNegativeButton("Back to Main Menu",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                    int arg1) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,
                                        HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });
                alert.show();
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also set the third button via `setNeutralButton(..)`.

Three buttons on `AlertDialog` is max. If you go beyond that you need to use `Dialog` and set custom view via `setContentView(view)`. In this View you can have whatever content: buttons, layouts, widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `setNeutralButton()`. But thats it (for a reason). Dialogs would be too cluttered with more buttons. If you need more options, rather build a normal activity or switch to a different dialog type (e.g. an AlertDialog with a list).